# Generating function of exponential integrals

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, generating-functions, closed-form

When studying the integral 
$$f(x,y)=\int_0^\infty \exp\left[-x\mathrm{e}^{-t}-y\cosh t\right]\mathrm d t,$$
I arrived at the handier result (especially for studying the asymptotics)
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-)^{n-1}\frac{(x+\frac y2)^n}{n!}\mathrm{E}_n(\frac y2).$$
(Where $\mathrm{E}_n(x)=\int_1^\infty t^{-n}\mathrm{e}^{-xt}\mathrm d t\;$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ order exponential integral.)
So now $f$ is just the generating function of the exponential integrals. Is there any chance that $f$ has a closed form ?

**EDIT** Some of the thoughts I have on how to find a closed form.

With a change of variables and an extra term $\mathrm{E}_0(y)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{y}$, I define the exponential generating function of exponential intagrals as
$$g(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}(-)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}\mathrm{E}_n(y)$$
We use the relation $\partial_x\mathrm{E}_n(x)=-\mathrm{E}_{n-1}(x)$ for $n\geq1$ ($\partial_x$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x$)
and we obtain the partial differential equation
$$\partial_x\partial_y g(x,y)=g(x,y).$$
Posing $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, we can transform this equation into an equation
for $h(u,v)=g(x,y)$
$$\partial^2_uh(u,v)-\partial^2_vh(u,v)=h(u,v).$$

This is known as the homogeneous Klein-Gordon equation, it has a lot of known solutions (for instance see the *Handbook of partial differential equations* by Andrei Polyanin).

**EDIT 2**

From what I know, we must have $h(u,0)=g(\frac u2,\frac u2)=\mathrm{K}_0(u)$ for $u>0$. We also can find, as @tired wrote, $g(0,y)=\mathrm{E}_1(y)$.
We also have $\partial_v h=\frac12\partial_xg-\frac12\partial_yg$ then
$$\partial_vh(u,0)=-\int_0^\infty\sinh t\;\exp\left[-u\cosh t\right]\mathrm dt=-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-u}}{u}=-\mathrm{E}_0(u).$$
As it appears in the *Handbook of partial differential equations*, the solution is then given 
$$\begin{split}h(u,v)&=\frac12\mathrm{K}_0(u+v)+\frac12\mathrm{K}_0(u-v)
+\frac v2\int_{u-v}^{u+v}\frac{\mathrm{I}_1\left(\sqrt{v^2-(u-\xi)^2}\right)}
{\sqrt{v^2-(u-\xi)^2}}\mathrm{K}_0(\xi)\mathrm d\xi\\&
\quad+\frac12\int_{u-v}^{u+v}\mathrm{I}_0\left(\sqrt{v^2-(u-\xi)^2}\right)\mathrm{E}_0(\xi)\mathrm d\xi,
\end{split}$$
This is far from being the closed form I hoped for. However, the form given by @tired makes me keep hope.

Comment: $E_n(x)$ is the closed form. What do you expect exactly ?. As far as I know, it is related to the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @JJacquelin. I am looking for a closed form of $f$ or $g$ or $h$.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? if you know the solutions for this DE what is the point?

Comment: @tired. The problem is to find the right solution among a big lot of possible solutions.

Comment: so you are looking for the correct boundary conditions?

Comment: @tired. Yes, that's part of the job. I know that $h(x,0)=K_0(x)$ thanks to Abramowitz & Stegun. But, I would need at least another condition. Actually when I asked the question, I was persuaded that the series for $f$ was known, but I could not find it anywhere and I started to worry there was no closed form, and I started to try doing the computation myself.

Comment: $f(y/2,y)=-\text{Ei}(-y/2)$. Does this help? ($f(0,y)=K_0(y)$ is equivalent to the bc you already found i guess)

Comment: @tired. How did you arrive at this result ? Note that $-\mathrm{Ei}(-x)=\mathrm{E}_1(x)$.